# Java programmatic way to update Schema or DTDs for XML files?

Tags: java, xml, dom, schema

Is there a way to use Java (build-in or third party library) to update an XML files XSD or DTD declarations?

For example, maybe we want to automatically update:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app id="WebApp">
...
```

To

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

Notice how I removed the DTD, added an XML declaration thing, and then also created schema declaration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dom4j had what I need but I needed the help from 2 stackoverflow links. (Editing soon to add those)